# What's the phrase "10 years" used for in the sentence "I'm 10 years your senior"

Tags: grammar

Is the phrase "10 years" a noun phrase?
Can I say "I'm your 10 years senior"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a fixed expression:

> *Senior* is used when indicating how much older one person is than another. For example, if someone is ten years your senior, they are
> ten years older than you.
>
> - *She became involved with a married man many years her senior.*

[[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/senior#:%7E:text=Senior%20is%20used%20when%20indicating,man%20many%20years%20her%20senior.)]

'n years your/my/her etc senior' is a fixed expression. You can't say "I'm your 10 years senior," but you *can* say "I'm his senior by ten years."

'10 years' is a measure phrase.

Comment: Also:  I'm ten years your senior.

Comment: +1 :) To add more detail about the mechanics of the phrase: in the related expression *10 miles distant*: "10 miles" functions as an adverb modifying the adjective 'distant.' I believe *10 years senior* follows the exact same grammatical pattern, which would make "10 years" also an adverb phrase (modifying "senior").

Comment: No; '10 years her senior' has the determiner, which '10 miles distant' doesn't.

Comment: I would call it a prepositional phrase with an implicit preposition.  Zero prep.

Comment: Another fixed expression ‍, English is so hard

Comment: Is the phrase "I'm his senior by ten years" really in common use?  I've never heard it, even in contexts where I have encountered "I'm ten years his senior."

Comment: I've certainly met it, and [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/senior), [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/senior), [CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/20-30-etc-years-senior) and [OLD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/senior_2) for instance have it.

Comment: How does that belong here rather than, for instance, in SE English Language Learners?

Comment: I'd say it's a strange idiom, and not all that common (witness LSpice's comment) while certainly being idiomatic, RG.

Answer (score 1):

“I was 10 years her senior” can mean.

(i) I was older than her by 10 years

or

(ii) I was her boss for 10 years

In (i) we have I was 10 years her senior = I was her senior by 10 years. – I was, by 10 years, her senior.

In (ii) we have I was 10 years her senior = I was her boss for 10 years - I was, for 10 years, her boss.

These constructions date back to Old English when the dative case would imply the prepositions **to, for** and (arguably*) **by**.

It is possible in English to classify a noun as an adverbial noun (a.k.a. adverbial objectives) see [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Adverbial-Nouns.htm#Time).

Compare

*I was 10 years a prisoner = I was a prisoner for 10 years. -> I was, for 10 years, a prisoner* and

*I made it myself -> I made it by myself* and

*It is £10 a foot – It is £10 for a foot.*

*The instrumental case in Old English is disputed and was, I believe, if it existed, similar to the dative.

Comment: (iii) I joined the company ten years before her. (i.e. I have ten years seniority, but the same grade.)

Comment: I would consider both (i) and (iii) to be perfectly unremarkable and natural, but while (ii) is _possible_ and you may see it in older texts, it’s not very likely to ever be heard in conversation. I don’t think I’ve ever heard anyone express the notion of ‘having been X for Y amount of time’ as ‘having been Y time X’; ‘I was her boss for ten years’ would be the only natural-sounding way of phrasing it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet the problem for me is that I've never heard "senior" used to mean "superior" or "supervisor."  But "X for Y amount of time" certainly can be expressed as "Y amount of time X" even if it is rather old-fashioned sounding.  I was ten years her boss.  _Twelve Years a Slave._  I was three weeks in Greece.  He was 20 minutes in the shop.  It's no longer colloquial, perhaps, but you will certainly find examples.

Comment: @phoog I’ve definitely heard ‘senior’ to mean ‘superior’ in a workplace context; that didn’t stick out to me as odd (cf. also _senior officer_). And yes, there are certainly examples (_Twelve Years a Slave_ came to my mind as well), but I don’t think I’ve ever heard anyone actually use this construction in natural speech – it’s quite distinctly marked as literary and old-fashioned to me.

Comment: Since "N years X's senior" is a common way to say N years older than X", it would be unusual to use it as an instance of the "X's Y for N years" general pattern. So even though it *could* be interpreted that way, it's not idiomatic.

Comment: Agree with those saying (ii) is not natural; "x years their senior" is a fixed phrase that refers to age. While "senior" does refer to superiority in the workplace, that phrase construction isn't correct for referring to anything other than age. (ii) is analogous to "I was 10 years her friend", which isn't correct either.